# No me esta actualizando un registro me dice que no lo puedo dejar nulo

Tags: mysql, laravel

El problema que tengo es que no puedo actualizar el nombre a la hora de enviar el formulario me dice que el campo que tengo en la base no puede estar **null** que seria el campo `name` del primer `text` el segundo al parecer si me lo agarra pero el primero no.

```
{{Form::open(array( 'url'=>'users_editar','id'=>'formulario','method'=>'put'))}}
    <div class="form-group">
       {{Form::label('name','Nombre')}}
       {{Form::text('name',$id->name,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
    </div>
    <hr>
       <h3>Lista de roles</h3>
       <div class="form-group">
       <ul class="list-unstyled">
          @foreach( $roles as $role)
          <li>
            <label>
               {{Form::checkbox('roles[]',$role->id,null)}}
               {{$role->name}}
               <em>({{$role->description ?:'N/A'}})</em>
            </label>
          </li>
          @endforeach
       </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           {{Form::submit('Guardar'),['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-primary']}}
       </div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Esta es mi **ruta** la cual si me llega al controlador pero no me actualiza:

```
 Route::put('users_editar{user}','UserController@update')->name('users.update')
        ->middleware('permission:users.edit');
```

Este es mi **controlador** el cual no me actualiza el primer registro de usuarios:

```
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
//        actualizar usuario
        $user->update($request->all());

//        actualizar roles
        $user->roles()->attach($request->get('roles'));

        return redirect()->route('users.edit',$user->id)->with('info','Usuario actualizado con exito');

    }
```

Este es el **error** que me tira:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id'
>   cannot be null (SQL: insert into `role_user` (`created_at`, `role_id`,
>   `updated_at`, `user_id`) values (2019-03-07 06:25:38, 1, 2019-03-07
>   06:25:38, ))

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante claro, `user_id` no puede ser nulo, y no estas asignando ningun

Comment: Vale, disculpa, no vi la función sync. Prueba pasando false como segundo argumento `sync($request->get('roles'), false)`

Comment: me sigue igual con el mismo problema

Comment: ¿Te salta el mismo error si usas `attach()` en lugar de `sync()`?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba cambiando la variable $id por $user, y has lo mismo en la ruta.

```
public function update(Request $request,User $user)
```

¿Como tienes las rutas? puedes poner el `php artisan route:list`

Comment: me faltaba colocarle el id ala ruta el problema que tengo ahora es que no me encuentra la vista por que cuando le doy al boton de actualizar me tira un error 404

Comment: ya actualice mi respuesta ahora el problema que me da es que no me encuentra el controlador y me tira un error 404

Comment: La ruta esta mal, `users_editar/{user}` seria la manera correcta

Comment: si ya actualice mi respuesta el problema que tengo ahora es que no me encuentra mi ruta me dice un error 404

Comment: ya lo pude resolver tenia un problema en mi ruta  de mi formulario el cual le cambien users_editar por users.update